# Excel References problem in C# code

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop, vba

I have a spreadsheet that is using the WORKDAY() function in Excel (which I believe lives in the Analysis Toolpak library/package/whatever you call it in Excel). When I open this spreadsheet manually and call this function it behaves fine.

I have a macro that references the cell that the WORKDAY() function is used in:

```
Dim startDate as Date
startDate = Cells(1,1)
```

When I run the macro after opening the spreadsheet manually this code executes fine. The problem is when I try and open the spreadsheet and run the macro from my C# code. It will then fail when it tries to get the value for startDate. When I look at that cell I see a #VALUE! reference error. It seems like it is not loading the correct references when I open the spreadsheet from my C# code.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could it be a problem with macros being disabled in general when opening through C#?  Can you confirm that you can run any macro at all?

Comment: The macro runs. It stops halfway through the macro on the line that tries to set the date.

Comment: If you open Excel via automation it doesn't automatically loads add-ins: you need to do that in your code. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213489

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I had to do is force the loading of the `.xla` add-in using:

```
app.Workbooks.Open(file_name)
```

where `app` is an instance of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application`
if it already open then nothing happens, otherwise it loads the analysis addin. To find the path for the add-in it depends on the version of Office

- Office 11: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\Library\Analysis\ANALYS32.XLL
- Office 12: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\Library\Analysis\ANALYS32.XLL